# Appcelerator - File storage fail

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I copy a video into /Documents/videos/xxxxxx.mp4 and then, when I close the app and restart it, this error appear when I want to get the file:

```
nativeReason = "Could not open file stream for file at path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/055CE45C-28EC-46F5-9609-F16E357B682E/Documents/videos/1458044667778.mp4\nFile does not exist at path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/055CE45C-28EC-46F5-9609-F16E357B682E/Documents/videos/1458044667778.mp4";
```

But I can see this file at the directory:

[image]

Whats the problem?? This occur on iOS, Ti.SDK 5.2.0.GA

My code:

```
            if(OS_IOS){
                Ti.API.debug("Media: " + this.get("media").nativePath);
                var infile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(this.get("media").nativePath); //!
            }else{
                var infile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(this.get("media"));
            }
            Ti.API.debug('infile: ' + infile.exists());

            var tempFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "videos/");

            if(!tempFile.exists())
                tempFile.createDirectory(); //create videos directory

            var tempFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "videos/" + new Date().getTime() + ".mp4");
            Ti.API.debug('tempFile ' + tempFile.exists()); // tempsFile is always empty

            if(OS_IOS){

                if (infile.exists() && (!tempFile.exists()) ) { //copy infile to videos/
                    tempFile.write(infile.read());
                }

            }else{ //Android

                infile.copy(tempFile.nativePath); //copy infile to videos/
            }   

//Get video, the path saved is correct
    var vid = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(video.get("videoFile"));
```

Comment: The code that you past here is to save the video, how do you get the video once you have save it ?

Comment: Added my line to get the video in the question.

Comment: Try to save the video file name in `video.get("videoFile")` and get the video this way : `Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "videos/"+video.get("videoFile"));`

Comment: It works!!! but why not the other way???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Ti.Filesystem.getFile() all relative paths are currently interpreted as relative to the Resources directory, not to the current context. This is a known issue that will be addressed in a future release. : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-getFile

So, you need to save the video file name in `video.get("videoFile")` and get the video this way : `Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "videos/"+video.get("videoFile"));`

Comment: Thank you for all.